# Hemoglobin equilibrium - effect of increased carbon dioxide and lactic acid

Tags: equilibrium, biochemistry

The binding of oxygen by haemoglobin giving oxy-haemoglobin is partially regulated by the concentration of $\ce{H3O+}$ and dissolved in $\ce{CO2}$ in blood
$$\ce{HbO2 + H3O+ +CO2<=>H+.Hb.CO2 + O2 + H2O}$$ 
If there is production of lactic acid and $\ce{CO2}$ in a muscle during excretion then is more oxygen released or is more $\ce{HbO2}$ formed?

Comment: Is this homework? What research have you done? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: See im a bit confused with this...i wanted to know if my guess is correct...is it oxygen because if we add more CO2 equilibrium should shift to right..i just wanted someone to verify...no its not my homework...just practising problems..